# How can I check a condition if the path equal a folder name?

Tags: c#, file, path

Path = c:\users\source\ **reports**\projects\ .file

How can I check if the projects folder inside a folder name == "reports"?

for example: 
If (reports)
.....do a condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GetDirectory()` and `Filename()` methods from the `System.IO.Path` class as follows:

```
string path = @"c:\users\source\reports\projects\.file";

string parent = Path.GetDirectory(path);
// parent == "@"c:\users\source\reports\projects"

string grandparent = Path.GetDirectory(parent);
// grandparent == "@"c:\users\source\reports"

string filename = Path.Filename(grandparent);
// filename == "reports"
```

Now you can check whether `filename` is `"reports"`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) class, which can be instantiated with a path string. This class has properties that represent a directory, including `Parent`, which returns a new `DirectoryInfo` for the parent folder. It also has a `Name` property which is the name of the folder (not to be confused with `FullName`, which is the full path to the folder, which we don't need).

So, in your example we need to the the `Parent` of the `Parent`, and then compare the `Name` to `"reports"`:

```
var path = @"c:\users\source\reports\projects\FileName.ext";

if (new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.Parent.Name == "reports")
{
    Console.WriteLine("found it!");
}
```

If you want to do a more detailed search, like the first `Parent` is called "projects", you can do that, too. This also shows how you can do a case-insensitive comparison, which may be a good idea:

```
var path = @"c:\users\source\reports\projects\FileName.ext";

var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

if (dirInfo.Parent.Name.Equals("projects", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    dirInfo.Parent.Parent.Name.Equals("reports", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file is in 'projects', which is in the 'reports' folder.");
}
```